# Replace each string of one or more blanks with a single blank

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

This was already asked, but I made my own program and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
int c;
char blank;


while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        putchar(c);
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') {
            putchar('');
        }
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Basically, replace space with nothing is what I did. But it doesn't work. If I put '1' instead of '' it replaces spaces with 1s so I don't know what's the problem

Comment: what do you expect `putchar('')` to do?  `''` is not a valid character constant.  If you don't want to output anything, simply do nothing.

Comment: If you don't want to output the character, don't call `putchar()` at all.

Comment: Additional problem: The second `getchar` in the loop can also return `EOF`, so you might have to skip the `putchar` after the conditional `if` block.

Comment: Fun fact: the whole program can be reduced to a one-liner, empty `for` loop. `for(char s[99]; scanf(" %s", s) == 1; printf("%s ", s));`

Comment: Nice solution @davide though this will also strip newlines from the input

Comment: @Davide `scanf(" %s", s)` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Suggested [one liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485690/replace-each-string-of-one-or-more-blanks-with-a-signle-blank#comment115776887_65485690) has differing output when input is `"abc"`.as it appends a space.

Comment: You are right, it's not an equivalent program. But it was fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error in your code is in the way you have used the `putchar()` function. When using `putchar()` you must put a character inside, such as `putchar('a')`, but you cannot leave it empty. This is why you are receiving the error:

> error: empty character constant

Basically, `putchar()` must put a character and whatever is in between the single quotes: `''`, is not a character.

To fix your code: you should remove the `putchar('')` line entirely, so your code would looks like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        putchar(c);
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') {

        }
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: Corner: If input ends with `x<blank><blank>`, code will attempt to print `'x'`, `' '`, `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

#I would like to suggest my code:

```
    int c,nb=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
      if(c==' '){
         ++nb;
         if(nb>1){
           continue;
         }
         putchar(c);
    }
      if(c!=' '){
         nb=0;
         putchar(c);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).